# Unable to create cluster. VPC is greyed out when launching Redshift Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-vpc, subnet, vpc

**Can't select the default VPC. Error: VPC associated with db subnet group does not exist**

Error image 1 -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dp4Y.png

Error Image 2 -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulytq.png

VPC Dashboard -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVCNi.png

Subnets ->    https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNdnt.png

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems to me that you don't have a subnet group. In redshift, subnet groups are **not created by default**, unlike in RDS:

> You **must have at least one cluster subnet group** defined to provision a cluster in a VPC.

You can create a subnet group following the instructions from docs:

- [Creating a cluster subnet group](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/managing-cluster-subnet-group-console.html)

Comment: Thank you! Created subnet group and now I can select the default VPC.